Subspace proofs - Sheldon Axler's "Linear Algebra Done Right"
I've just recently started learning linear algebra using Sheldon Axler's "Linear Algebra Done Right" textbook (third edition), and I've been struggling a lot with subspace proof, specifically proving that the subset is closed under addition and scaler multiplication.
Here's a sample problem I've been working on:

Show that the set of differentiable real-valued functions $f$ on the interval
$(−4, 4)$ such that $f'(−1) = 3f (2)$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{(-4,4)}$

Definitions:
If $S$ is a set, then $\mathbf{F}^S$ denotes the set of functions from $S$ to $\mathbf{F}$.
My Process:
Let $U$ be the set of differentiable real-valued functions $$ on the interval
$(−4, 4)$ such that $f'(−1) = 3 f (2)$
First step is to prove that $0 \in U$. The set must contain the element $0$, and this function has a $0$ derivative as well therefore:
$$0'(-1) = 3 \cdot 0(2) = 0 = 3 \cdot 0 = 0$$
The next part is where I'm confused though, since I know intuitively that this set is closed under addition and scalar multiplication to a degree, but I don't know how to show it. Any pointers? (also some help on my formatting would be appreciated since I don't have much experience in writing these types of proofs.)

If $f$ satisfies $f'(-1) = 3f(2)$, and $g$ satisfies $g'(-1) = 3g(2)$, and you define $h:=f+g$, then does $h$ satisfy $h'(-1) = 3h(2)$?

right so $h'(-1) = f'(-1) + g'(-1) = 3f(2) + 3g(2) = 3(f(2) + g(2)) = 3(f + g)(2) = 3h(2)$
but I'm still sort of confused how that helps to prove that the subset is closed under addition could you please explain a bit? (Sorry if this seems like a stupid question)

A comment on your formatting/flow. People read left to right. When you put "$0'(-1) = 3 \cdot 0(2) = 0 = 3 \cdot 0 = 0$" in a single line, you are smushing together three complete ideas: If $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$, then (1) $f'(-1) = 0$, (2) $3 f(2) = 0$, and (3) $f'(-1) = 3f(2)$. But in your one string of symbols, these ideas appear in this order: (1), (3), and finally (2) backwards. Instead, make one separate line for each of $f'(-1)$ and $3f(2)$, and then assert that the values are equal.


The next part is where I'm confused though, since I know intuitively that this set is closed under addition and scaler multiplication to a degree, but I don't know how to show it. Any pointers?

Remember that
$$
(f+g)' = f'+g' \qquad (\alpha f)' = \alpha f
$$
provided $f,g$ are differentiable and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.
So, given that $f,g \in U$, show that $f+g \in U$. This means:

$f+g$ has domain $(-4,4)$
$f+g$ is differentiable on the interval
$f+g$ takes on real values
$f+g$ has derivative of $3 \cdot (f+g)(2)$ at $-1$

Then repeat for the function $\alpha f$, when $f \in U$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.
